# WPF binding linear gradient property with Button

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I want to bind the gradient property to the button. I am using below code. I am able to bind the style. Can you suggest how should i bind the linergradientbrush property??

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="buttonStyleGradient"  EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFACC3F5" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
       <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
           <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Vrinda"/>
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4" />
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
       </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources><Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" >                  
                <Label>Home</Label>
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `buttonStyleGradient` to the `buttonStyle` as a `Background` Property:

```
<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Vrinda"/>
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4" />
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource buttonStyleGradient}" />
</Style>
```

And if you don't want to add it to the style, you can manually put in on the button like this:

```
<Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Background="{StaticResource buttonStyleGradient}" >
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a property to apply the gradient to, try Background:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource buttonStyleGradient}"/>
```